# Remove everything in brackets at the end

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to removing everything that is is brackets `()` if (and only if) they are at the end and not do match the following pattern `\(\d{4}\p{Pd}\d{4}\) *`. This pattern is nothing more than date range in brackets, eg. `(1920-2988)`.

For instance, I'd like to match/capture (for removing, ie. `string.replaceAll(my_regex_here, "")`):

- foo bar `(blah)`
- foo bar (blah) blah `(blah)`

I don't like to match:

- some (blah) data
- some date following (1920-1921).

I have the following regex: [\s*(.+?)\s*$](https://regex101.com/r/0kEYo2/1). It tends to match too much:

- some data `(..) match (match)`
- some data `(1920-1977)`

Comment: Is there some reason you have to do it with a single replaceAll call and no other code?

Comment: @VGR I'd like to avoid another private method cleaning string (I have already a bunch of these).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negative look ahead to avoid date ranges, then actually match it using `[^()]+?`:

```
\s*\(                  # Match 0+ spaces, a '(',
(?!\d{4}\p{Pd}\d{4}\)) # which is not followed by a date range and a ')',
[^()]+                 # 1+ non-parenthesis characters and
\)\s*$                 # ')' then 0+ spaces right before the end of line.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/49BjC0/2).

The above regex will not match:

```
parentheses with no content ()
years with more than 4 digits (1234-56789)
or less than 4 (123-4567)
nested ((brackets))
mismatched (brackets
```